# Parallel program for multiplication of matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to write a parallel program for multiplication of matrix in Matlab. I have tried with below code but I could not do it. I don't want to do it with a GPU.

```
A = pascal(3);
B = magic(3);
m = 3; n = 3;
par for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        C(i,j) = A(i,:)*B(:,j);
    end
end
```

How can I parallelise the above code?

Comment: I might be splitting hairs here, but what's wrong with `C = A * B`?

Comment: Also do you have the parallel computing toolbox and have your initialized the pool of workers etc?

Comment: also is it a typo? `par for` should be one word `parfor`...

Comment: Also worth noting is that `paralyze` means, approximately, to render completely incapable of motion.  This is often what happens when we first try to `parallelise` a program though it is not usually our intention.

Comment: Ya i have parallel toolbox and i have initialized the pool of workers..

Comment: Error is that i cant use parfor as loop variable is used inside the loop. So how can i paralyze? i

Answer (score 1):

Are `distributed` arrays OK?

```
d = distributed.rand(1024);
result = d * d;
```

Note that MATLAB's matrix-matrix multiplication is implicitly multithreaded, and so will be faster than anything using `distributed` or `parfor` unless you have multiple machines at your disposal (or a GPU).